# How to create parent/child column based on a work breakdown structure in Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column that looks like the first column 'WBS #". How can I manipulate this column with Python/pandas code to label each row as either parent or child in the way they are in the second column "Parent/Child"?

df:

| WBS # | Parent/Child |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Parent |
| 1.1 | Parent |
| 1.1.1 | Child |
| 1.1.2 | Parent |
| 1.1.2.1 | Parent |
| 1.1.2.1.1 | Parent |
| 1.1.2.1.1.1 | Child |
| 1.1.2.1.1.2 | Child |
| 1.1.2.1.2 | Child |
| 1.1.2.1.3 | Child |
| 1.1.2.2 | Child |

The goal is to be able to have each row properly labelled as either parent or child so all of the child elements can be rolled up appropriately.

Comment: Please format the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last part of each WBS to get the parents, then use `isin` combined with `numpy.where`:

```
parents = df['WBS #'].str.replace('\.\d+$', '', regex=True).unique()
# array(['1', '1.1', '1.1.2', '1.1.2.1', '1.1.2.1.1'], dtype=object)

df['Parent/Child'] = np.where(df['WBS #'].isin(parents), 'Parent', 'Child')
```

output:

```
          WBS # Parent/Child
0             1       Parent
1           1.1       Parent
2         1.1.1        Child
3         1.1.2       Parent
4       1.1.2.1       Parent
5     1.1.2.1.1       Parent
6   1.1.2.1.1.1        Child
7   1.1.2.1.1.2        Child
8     1.1.2.1.2        Child
9     1.1.2.1.3        Child
10      1.1.2.2        Child
```